# Proper use of internal class when testing with generic base test class

Tags: c#, unit-testing

TL;DR
I can't seem to get **InternalsVisibleTo** to work with my Unit Tests

### Background

I'm currently developing a library where I'd like to make some (but not all) classes internal to avoid confusing the users. Only SOME of the classes should be public from that dll.

I figured this would be a good project to learn how to deal with the *internal* keyword in C#.

Whenever I make a new project, I find myself using a variant of DDD, where I'll split up responsibilities into different DLL's, but for the sake of this question, think of my project structure like this (from top to bottom):

- The executable using my library
- The library that I'm developing
- A unit test library for unit-testing my library
- Testing tools library, containing base class for all unit tests

For a working example of the architecture, you can look at my [HelloWorld project](https://github.com/digitaldias/HelloWorld) over on github. This example does not replicate the problem here though, it only serves to illustrate how I typically layer my code.

I'll often create a base class for my unit tests that creates mocks for any type that I'm testing, i.e. this example:

```cs
public class TestsFor<TInstance> where TInstance : class
{
    protected MoqAutoMocker<TInstance> AutoMock { get; set; }
    protected TInstance Instance { get; set; }

    public TestsFor()
    {
        AutoMock = new MoqAutoMocker<TInstance>();

        RunBeforeEachUnitTest(); // virtual

        Instance = AutoMock.ClassUnderTest;

        RunAfterEachUnitTest(); // virtual
    }
}
```

### Problem

The Unit-Tests that I write often take them form of:

```cs
public class ReportServiceTests : TestsFor<ReportService>
{
    [Fact]
    public async Task CreateReport_WhenCalled_LogsTheCall()
    {
        // Act
        await Instance.CreateReport();

        // Assert            
        GetMockFor<ILogger>().Verify(logger => logger.Enter(Instance, nameof(Instance.CreateReport)), Times.Once());
    }
}
```

Where each Unit test will derive the **TestsFor<T>** class in order to give me an out-of-the-box mocked test class. However, even though I've marked my internal classes with **InternalsVisibleTo** pointing them to both the unit-test assembly as well as the test-tools assembly (where the unit-test baseclass is) I'm STILL getting *Inconsistent accessibility* errors.

Does anyone know how to get around this?

Comment: Depending on how your mocking library works, it may be creating assemblies on the fly and those assemblies may also need to be identified with InternalsVisibleTo. Hopefully it's using consistent names!

Comment: Which mocking library you are using?

Comment: If you are using Moq, then add this `[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("DynamicProxyGenAssembly2")]`

Comment: I am using Moq as the mocking library

Comment: Adding DynamicProxyGenAssembly2 didn't help me, still the same deal, scanning thru all my assemblies now, but no luck yet

Comment: I think this one cannot be solved easily, so I'll leave it up here in case I'm wrong, but using **internal** seems to be blocking me from using any kind of unit-testing baseclasses, so I'll see if I can work around it somehow.

Comment: Can you not testing internals at all? Test only public classes, internals will be tested through them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you're running into is that you are trying to create a class that is more accessible than its base class.

You can delegate instead of deriving:

```
public class ReportServiceTests
{
    private Tests tests = new Tests();

    [Fact]
    public async Task CreateReport_WhenCalled_LogsTheCall()
    {
        tests.CreateReport_WhenCalled_LogsTheCall();
    }

    private class Tests : TestsFor<ReportService>
    {
        public async Task CreateReport_WhenCalled_LogsTheCall()
        {
            // Act
            await Instance.CreateReport();

            // Assert            
            GetMockFor<ILogger>().Verify(logger => logger.Enter(Instance, nameof(Instance.CreateReport)), Times.Once());
        }
    }
}
```